# How to calculate total distance with Google map API V2

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I want calculate distance with Google map when I add a line, but I'm stuck here. This is my Javascript:

```
function startLine() 
{
  select("line_b");
  var color   = getColor(false);
  var line    = new GPolyline([], color);

  startDrawing(line, "Distance  " , function() 
  {
    var cell        = this;
    var len         = line.getLength();
    cell.innerHTML  = (Math.round(len / 10) / 100).toFixed(2) + " km";
    cell.innerHTML  = x;

  }, color);

    startDrawing(line, "Total  " , function() 
  {
    var cell        = this;
    var len         = line.getLength();
    cell.innerHTML  = ((Math.round(len / 10) / 100)*0.25)+x.toFixed(2) + " km";
  }, color);

}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why are you still using API V-2

Comment: If you are really using the [deprecated Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), please change the tag.

Answer (score 0):

use API v-3.. and read documentation. It often works :)

Althought, you could post more information about your problem..

Comment: google improved much from V2 to V3.. and the related documentation gained many benefits ;)

I may have seemed unkind with my previous response, but if you still need some help..